# Best way to define a python function with two required arguments where one can have one of two types?

Tags: python

I have a method `collide` which takes either:

- one `Ball`-object and an `int` and calculates the ball's velocity after it collides with a wall, or
- two ball objects and calculates their velocities after they collide with each other.

My function looks like this:

```
def collide(self, ball_1, arg2): 
    """Takes {one ball and a wall} or {two balls} and sets their velocities to the correct ones for after the collision.

    ball_1 is an instance of ball

    arg2 is either Ball or int (wall_no)

    collide sets the new velocities for two balls colliding or for one ball colliding with a wall.
    """


    if not isinstance(ball_1, Ball):
        ArgumentError("ball_1 must be Ball")

    if not (isinstance(arg2, int) or isinstance(arg2, Ball)):
        ArgumentError("ball_2 must be int or Ball")

    if isinstance(arg2, int): ## CHECKING IF int

        wall_no = arg2

        ### Changing the velocity of the sole ball ###

    elif isinstance(arg2, Ball): ## CHECKING IF Ball
        ball_2 = arg2

    ### Loads of linear algebra and mechanics ###

    else:
        raise ValueError('Invalid arguments')
```

I wonder what the best practice is with regards to handling function arguments in a situation such as this one. I don't really like having an argument that could be one of two different types. What's the recommended way of doing it?

EDIT:

```
class Board:

    def __init__(self, width = 100, height = 100, sps = 2):     
        """A board with (x,y) = (0,0) in the bottom left corner, 
        like the first quadrant of a coordinate system.

        width, height; no of cells
        sps; steps per second
        step_size; step size in terms of time. unit: seconds.
        """
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.sps = 2
        self.timestep = 1/sps
        self.balls = set()
    def collide():
        #...
```

Comment: Consider defining two functions.

Comment: Function overloading is what you're looking for.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1this does not exist in Python.

Comment: Correct, bruno. I thought of it, too, but realised that it's not an option.

Comment: @Sandi define two distinct functions and just drop all those isinstance checks.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Bruno, let's say that I define a new function `collide_wall_ball(self, ball, wall_no)`. Are you saying I shouldn't even check the type of the `ball` and `wall_no` arguments that are passed into that function?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers That's a very sad design choice.

Comment: You say it's a method but on what object?

Comment: MSeifert see my edit

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1, I think all of us would benefit a lot more if you'd explain why you think so.

Comment: @Sandi there's no use in defensive typechecking here definitely. Either you pass the right kind of object and the function works or you don't and some exception will happen anyway because the given object wont have the expected interface. Read about "duck typing"...

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 nothing prevents you from implementing a complex type-based multiple dispatch system in python - some brilliant minds already did actually and as a matter of fact no one uses their work. Perhaps is it not that needed from a practical pov?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would make collide as a function of your Ball class, and do something like this:

```
class Ball:
    def collide(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Ball):
            self.collideWithBall(other)
            other.collideWithBall(this) #might not want this line, depending on how you're organizing the logic.
        elif isinstance(other, int):
            self.collideWithWall(other)
        else:
            #error here

    def collideWithBall(self, otherBall):
        ### Loads of linear algebra and mechanics ###

    def collideWithWall(self, wallId):
        ### Changing the velocity of the sole ball ###
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a good idea

Comment: @Sandi happy to help.  I added another line in the first if, but you might not need it if the code thats calling collide handles all Balls.

Comment: The line isn't needed, collide sets the velocity for both balls. That seems like the best way to do it to me since the balls' velocities after the collision are interdependent.